# not running cron with casperjs

Tags: cron, casperjs

sh_run.sh file..

```
#!/bin/bash

PHANTOMJS_EXECUTABLE=/usr/local/bin/phantomjs /usr/local/bin/casperjs /home/test/html/run/site_check.js
```

Setting in crontab..

```
# cat /etc/crontab
45 0 * * *  root    sh /home/test/html/run/sh_run.sh
```

but casperjs not running..
crontab status is Rl..
what is Rl ??

```
# ps ax|grep phantomjs
28155 ?        Rl     0:18 /usr/local/bin/phantomjs /usr/local/casperjs/bin/bootstrap.js --casper-path=/usr/local/casperjs --cli /home/test/html/run/site_check.js
```

of course..

```
# casperjs site_check.js
```

is running..

add comment...

```
# sh sh_run.sh &
# ps ax|grep phantomjs
 1625 pts/0    Sl     0:01 /usr/local/bin/phantomjs /usr/local/casperjs/bin/bootstrap.js --casper-path=/usr/local/casperjs --cli /home/test/html/run/site_check.js
```

is running...

if ps status is Sl, data change.. (namely running..)

but ps status is Rl, data not change.. run by cron, status is always Rl.
Rl status does not change.

what problem? plz.. 
help me..

Comment: R - running (or runnable). l - multithreaded. Did you try to check the `man` page?

Comment: How do you know that it's not running? Do you expect some files to appear?

Comment: a few minutes data not changed.. so I guess not run..